# Why does the custom function I created return empty values? - DFS

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I'm currently studying on DFS and created a code like the following:

```py
>>> N = 4
>>> check_list = [False]*N
>>> output = []
>>> possible_combs = []
>>> A = [1,2,3,4]
>>> def dfs(depth, N, A):
        if depth == N:
            possible_combs.append(output)
            return 
        for i in range(N):
            if check_list[i]:
                continue
            check_list[i] = True
            output.append(A[i])
            dfs(depth+1, N, A)
            output.pop()
            check_list[i] = False
```

This is the code, and when I do the following, the `possible_combs` returns numbers empty lists:

```py
>>> dfs(0, N, A)    # N and A defined above
>>> possible_combs
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I thought that something was wrong with the output, so I tried printing the output when `depth==N` by adding `print(output)` in the first code:

```py
>>> def dfs(depth, N, A):
        if depth == N:
            possible_combs.append(output)
            print(output)
            return 
        for i in range(N):
            if check_list[i]:
                continue
            check_list[i] = True
            output.append(A[i])
            dfs(depth+1, N, A)
            output.pop()
            check_list[i] = False
>>> dfs(0, N, A)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 4]
[3, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 2]
[4, 2, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

and it prints out just fine. However, I can't find the reason why the `possible_combs` returns those empty list values. Can anybody help me on this??

Comment: Try ```possible_combs.append(output[:])```.

Comment: @ Henry Tjhia Nope still not working. This time, the `possible_combs` returns just `[]` instead of the `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]` shown in the above

Comment: I'm thinking that this has to do something with the output being made into an empty list again, due to the `output.pop()`, but I can't to find out why this would have effect on the `possible_combs.append(output)`, since the `output` was already appended to the `possible_combs`

Comment: @mtdot it reacehs N, since I' ve tested the `print(output)` on the `if depth==N`

Comment: try this `possible_combs.append([*output])` instead

Comment: @HenryTjhia In fact, this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

add `import copy`

change line to `possible_combs.append(copy.copy(output))`

Python passes lists by reference, so you need to copy the current version of output before adding it to possible_combs.

Comment: well that did work, but why would my code not work??

Comment: The value of `output` is changing during every subsequent DFS call. Since you call output.pop() in DFS, by the time all DFS calls are finished output=[], and Python passes lists by reference. So possible_combs will have bunch of empty lists because they are references to output, which is empty. Everything looks fine in your DFS function (if this was C++ your code will automatically work) but since Python passes lists by reference you were getting incorrect output.

Comment: I didn't know that Python passes lists by reference. Would it be fine if I understand that since the recursion does not stop until every possible outcome is finished, and when that recursion is finished, the `output = []`, so the `possible_combs` would have an empty list, since Python passes lists by reference?

Comment: exactly! `possible_combs` will just store the reference to `output` which is empty by the end of the DFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

***Stephen Mylabathula*** already explained.
you can use id(output) to know hash of list instance. Using this, you can find that you are doing pop and append operation on same list.

```py
print(id(output))
140214576196336
print(id(output[:]))
140214575515360
```

So instead of appending list to possible_outcome, append content or copy of list i.e. output[:]

```py
def dfs(depth, N, A):
        if depth == N:
            possible_combs.append(output[:])
            #print(output)
            return 
        for i in range(N):
            if check_list[i]:
                continue
            check_list[i] = True
            output.append(A[i])
            dfs(depth+1, N, A,)
            output.pop()
            check_list[i] = False
dfs(0, N, A)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This also helped too